# Can't bring up scala-ensime REPL in emacs

Tags: scala, emacs, emacs24, ensime

I've got ensime and scala-mode2 install in my emacs, and I successfully start the ensime server for my project, and then when I try to bring up scala-repl through M-c + M-v + z, I got the following error:   "apply: Wrong type argument: stringp, ("/Users/admin/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.4.jar" "/Users/admin/.ivy2/cache/org.kamranzafar/jtar/jars/jtar-2.2.jar" "/Users/admin/*/target/scala-2.11/classes" "/Users/admin/*/target/scala-2.11/test-classes")"

Comment: I guess this isn't really matter since I can start the console in sbt, But it would nice to make it work.

Comment: do you have this list of paths in your configuration? This is a type error.

Answer (score 0):

This might have been a transient error. This code has been refactored a lot recently, does it work now?

If not, follow the [Troubleshooting Guide](http://ensime.github.io/editors/emacs/troubleshooting/)